# Visual Studio for Mac- Error CS1902

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I just recently swapped my MS PC for an Mac, I'm trying to continue working on an MVC project, but I'm getting an error (Error CS1902: Invalid option 'portable' for /debug; must be full or pdbonly (CS1902)).

Are there any good documents that explain how to make it work? I have seen people porting MVC to .NET Core, but I can't get the analyser to work on my Mac (not sure it's supported yet).

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear - is this a .NET Core project you're trying to edit on your Mac? If not, it won't work.

Comment: Thats what the question says, I'm working from a Mac. I need to port an MVC project to .NET Core to make it work, or by using Mono. I'm not sore how to do the porting.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

I did two things.

1. I update the Microsoft.Net.Compliers via nuget.
   https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/
2. Change one value in the properties of project.
   https://johnharold.wordpress.com/2017/08/16/csc-error-cs1902-invalid-option-portable-for-debug-must-be-full-or-pdbonly-cs1902/

I wish you can solve the problem

Comment: But doesn't #2 defeat the purpose of being able to debug and set breakpoints in your code?

Comment: Additionally, I was able to build successfully after updating the Microsoft.Net.Compilers in Packages to 3.3.1 (was 1.0.0). Using the "Full" debug option worked without issues.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem when trying to use Visual Studio for Mac to build a solution that works fine in Windows. Turns out the `/debug:portable` flag was being passed to the build command, even though the 'Debug Information' was correctly set to 'Full' in my project settings. Search the build output for 'portable' and you will indeed find the flag there regardless of your settings.

The fix is to upgrade the Microsoft.Net.Compilers nuget package. In my case, it upgraded from 1.0 to 2.7, and then the project built successfully.

Comment: To upgrade in Visual Studio for Mac, expand the package list under the project, find 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers', right click and hit update.

Comment: This did not fix it for me. I installed the Microsoft.Net.Compilers package 2.10 and Visual Studio still adds /debug:portal to the command line even though I have the option set to full in the project configuration.

Answer (score -4):

Right click on the project in the solution explorer and go to 
Options, Build, Compiler and change Debug information to Full